# Printscreen the screen and save the image(VB)

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me, how can I printscreen my screen that can be saved in gif or jpeg format
locally in VB.net

Answer (score 1):

<sup>I know this question was asked *a long time* ago so I post this for posterity.</sup>

It's quite trivial to preform a screen capture operation using the [CopyFromScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yfzc507(v=vs.110).aspx) method in the [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Also, the [BitMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) class ships with a [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx) method; making this even more trivial.

```vb
Using image As New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)

    Using surface As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)
        surface.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location, Point.Empty, image.Size)
    End Using

    image.Save("C:\myimage.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

End Using
```

One possible solution when dealing with multiple monitors is to iterate, capture and save each screen as individual images. Place the above code inside the following *For Each Next* statement and replace *Screen.PrimaryScreen* with *monitor*. Be sure that you set a unique file name for each image.

```
For Each monitor As Screen In Screen.AllScreens
    '...
Next
```